# Is there a way to determine if a subdirectory is in the same filesystem from python when using os.walk?

Tags: python, unix

I'm writing a python script that uses os.walk() to walk a directory tree.  I'd like to give it the ability to skip subdirectories that are mounted to a different file system, the way `find -xdev` does.  Checking through the documentation on os.walk(), I didn't see any argument to pass in for it to do that automatically.  Is there something I can use to do the filtering myself?  Hopefully something that runs on both Linux and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[os.path.ismount()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a combination of the `os.stat` call and a filtering of the dirnames given by `os.walk` to do what you want. Something like this:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(somerootdir) :
    do_processing(root, dirs, files)
    dirs = [i for i in dirs if os.stat(os.path.join(root, i)).st_dev == os.stat(root).st_dev]
```

That should modify the list of directories to recurse into, by removing those which do not have the same device.

I have no idea on how it will work on OS X, but it seems to be working here in Linux, after a very little bit of testing.

Comment: dirs list should be modified using del or slice assignment. Otherwise you just rebind local variable dirs to new list instead of changing dirs list used by os.walk.