# How do I prevent Python's os.walk from walking across mount points?

Tags: python, linux, unix

In Unix all disks are exposed as paths in the main filesystem, so `os.walk('/')` would traverse, for example, `/media/cdrom` as well as the primary hard disk, and that is undesirable for some applications.

How do I get an `os.walk` that stays on a single device?

Related:

- [Is there a way to determine if a subdirectory is in the same filesystem from python when using os.walk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530645/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-subdirectory-is-in-the-same-filesystem-from-pyth/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530645/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-subdirectory-is-in-the-same-filesystem-from-pyth/530692#530692

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `os.walk` docs:

> When topdown is true, the caller can
>   modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice
>   assignment), and walk() will only
>   recurse into the subdirectories whose
>   names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search

So something like this should work:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(...):
  dirnames[:] = [
    dir for dir in dirnames
    if not os.path.ismount(os.path.join(root, dir))]
  ...
```

Comment: a brilliantly concise answer.

Comment: As noted on the other comment: You can fool this with symlinks deeper into another filesystem. A better approach is to save the st_dev of the initial path (e.g. `dev0 = os.stat(startpath).st_dev`) and filter as `dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if os.stat(os.path.join(root,d)).st_dev == dev0]`

Answer (score 3):

I think [os.path.ismount](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount) might work for you.  You code might look something like this:

```
import os
import os.path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    # Handle files.
    dirs[:] = filter(lambda dir: not os.path.ismount(os.path.join(root, dir)), 
                  dirs)
```

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571850/adding-elements-to-python-generators) helpful in building your solution.

*Thanks for the comments on filtering `dirs` correctly.

Comment: You can fix is by chinging your code to "dirs[:] = filter(...)" instead, mutating the list in-place rather than reassiging

Comment: You can fool this with symlinks deeper into another filesystem. A better approach is to save the st_dev of the initial path (e.g. `dev0 = os.stat(startpath).st_dev`) and filter as `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if os.stat(os.path.join(root,d)).st_dev == dev0]`

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk()` can't tell (as far as I know) that it is browsing a different drive. You will need to check that yourself.

Try using `os.stat()`, or checking that the root variable from `os.walk()` is not `/media`